# Browserify bundles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, browserify, browser-cache

Every time we release a new version of our software which is bundled using Browserify, we are finding that we need to ask our users to clear their cache using the regular methods of CTRL+F5 or diving into the browser settings. It is not ideal when there are a thousand or so users. We are trying to work out a way that we can perhaps get around this. I am open to all sorts of options.

Our project is ReactJS based, so runs in the browser and connects to back end services via a RESTful API. We do track which version is loaded and this is visible from within the console. Using the version number we can compare on two different machines that one user is running the latest version whereas someone else may not be.

The code is bundled into two separate files and I feel that this is where we should be looking.

Comment: Change the filename each time, like to add a version number.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the file name on each new release.
A hash of the file is an appropriate thing you could add.

Check out [md5ify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5ify) to add this to your project build.

If you implement this yourself, make sure to also load the correct filename in your `index.html` file.

**Edit:**

To automatically load the correct file you need to have a placeholder in your main html.

Then you need a `manifest.json` file that looks like following:

```
{
 "main.js": "main.[HASH].js"
}
```

This has to be created automatically after the bundling.
Now you can replace the placeholder with correct asset by doing a lookup in the `manifest` file.

You either have to write your own scripts for this or use something like `gulp` together with `browserify`.

Another solution would be `webpack`

Comment: This is helpful but I need the bundler to be able to insert the generated filename into the index.html for me. It is not a task we really want to carry out manually each time.

Comment: updated the answer. since I do not know your exact setup you can use it as a guideline.